# Adding commands to TeX-command-list not working on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, auctex

In my `.emacs` file, I added a few commands to the TeX-command-list, which works fine on my Ubuntu and Debian laptops. On my wife's Macbook however, when invoking the TeX-command-list (C-c C-c) it appears to be empty.

I use emacs 23 in Debian, and emacs 22 in OS X. Both load the .emacs file without errors.

This is what I put in my `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn 
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          (list "Count Words" "texcount -inc %s.tex"
        'TeX-run-command nil t))
 (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
      (list "Convert dvi to ps" "dvips -P pdf -G0 %s.dvi"
        'TeX-run-command nil t))
))
```

Has anybody come across a problem like this?

Comment: Is it possible the AUCTeX installation is different?  After verifying the AUCTeX installations are the same version on all three installations, the next step would be to have emacs versions being consistent across platforms.  Otherwise, you are going to end up with different .emacs files being needed for different situations.

Comment: I really only mentioned the other computers (where it works) to rule out syntax errors. The piece of code above should add those commands to the TeX command list, but in one case they don't appear. The question is: Is there a version of AUCTEX (or emacs), where above code does not work?